Adding additional targets on a duplicate is impossible on iPhone
The dialog box for adding more URLs to the list of originals on a duplicate Question is much too wide on an iPhone. It is physically impossible to complete that dialog box.
Pasting the URL of an original Question into the field is impossible.
Such is the case in both portrait and landscape positions of the phone.
This has been true for months, if not years.



Trying to actually type and search isn't really helpful either:






Also true for an iPhone SE running iOS 17.4.1 with all updates for Apple including the latest version of Safari browser.

If you have an enter key on your keyboard, clicking it while in the textfield submits the dialog as usual. You don't need the button

Cross-site duplicate: "Editing the duplicate list doesn't really work on mobile with the new responsive design"

I really thought they had fixed this, but I haven't, now, found any indication on MSO or MSE that it was actually fixed. Unfortunately, I had fixed it locally (and hadn't disabled that fix for testing, even though I thought I had), which resulted in my mistaken belief that I wasn't able to duplicate the problem (and, I assume, my mistaken belief that it was fixed a long time ago).

It's semi-usable on the Samsung Internet browser, but several columns are cut off on the leftt, and so it's especially hard to see what you're doing if you need to search for a dupe. Landscape orientation doesn't help.

Well, asking Duplicates usually always get DV'ed on 'Meta', especially if 2 Dupe-Targets already exist... (meaning the Asker didn't do any/much Research)... For me (I also DV'ed), because the Func involved in this Thread is only available to less than 0.1% of the Users on the Site, => only Gold Hammers in a Tag, nowhere (clearly) mentioned. // Any Gold Hammer Tag User should be able to find some "decent" PC at some point to add any extra Duplicate and shouldn't be expected to curate 'SO' from an 'iPhone' or any SmartPhone. // One of the 2 Dupe-Targets is now in [status-review] though...
